# Удаление строки в DataGrid с помощью delete, потерян фокус

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

После удаления строки в dataGrid с помощью клавиши delete, обновляется нумерация строк, но фокус который должен опуститься на следующую строку почему-то пропадает, я читал что вроде как Items.Refrehs в коде не самый удачный способ применять, но к сожалению большего я не нашёл. Gif прикладываю и код прикладываю, Спасибо!!!

```
    <Window x:Class="GroupStyle_in_DataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupStyle_in_DataGrid"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Numering x:Key="numering"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  EnableRowVirtualization="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" KeyDown="dataGrid_KeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="№"  Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource numering},
                    Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="16"
                                                      TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GroupStyle_in_DataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<EmployeeInfo> employees = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeInfo>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(10, "Иван", "Раздел №1"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(20, "Петр", "Раздел №2"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(30, "Саша", "Раздел №3"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(40, "Эдик", "Раздел №1"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(50, "Павел", "Раздел №2"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(60, "Сергей", "Раздел №3"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(70, "Женя", "Раздел №1"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(80, "Боря", "Раздел №2"));
            employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(90, "Коля", "Раздел №3"));
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = employees;

            CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription pgd = new PropertyGroupDescription("Department");
            cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(pgd);
        }

        private void dataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
                dataGrid.CommitEdit();
                dataGrid.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
        public class Numering : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                DataGridRow строка = value as DataGridRow;
                if (строка.DataContext.GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.NamedObject") return null;
                return строка.GetIndex() + 1;


            }
            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        public class EmployeeInfo
        {
            public EmployeeInfo(int id, string name, string department)
            {
                ID = id;
                Name = name;
                Department = department;
            }
            public int ID
            { get; set; }

            public string Name
            { get; set; }

            public string Department
            { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ох ох ох, а почему MVVM не используете? Удобней же будет работать, да и код красивее будет.

Comment: А что знаю пока, на более широты мыслей не хватает.

Comment: Советую вам все же перейти на MVVM и сделать правильную привязку. Ну а что касательно вашей проблемы - делайте костыль, запоминайте какой номер элемента был выделен и выделяйте после удаления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF как не крути - это MVVM паттерн, без него вам придется изобретать много велосипедов. Допустим, что бы решить вашу задачу, вам надо до `Refresh()` запомнить номер выделенной строки и после ее выделять заново...

Смотрите, простой MVVM пример, который уберет все эти "костыли":

Первый класс, некая view model того, как будет выглядеть наш элемент:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Далее делаем главную ViewModel, которая будет для примера содержать коллекцию и ее заполнение:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel(0, "Test 1"));
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel(1, "Test 2"));
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel(2, "Test 3"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
}
```

Привяжем все это дело:

```
private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = MainViewModel;
}
```

Ну, осталось Xaml разметку сделать, не поверите, всего одна строка! :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserDeleteRows="True" />
```

Запускаем и... Результат!

[image: Result]

Как видите, нету лишних методов, подписей на какие то события, обычная, грамотная привязка. Вам лишь останется реализовать нумерацию и остальной функционал.

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать, а как увидел в сообщении MVVM, чё то мне чуть плохо не стало:))))

Comment: @Евгений Ну MVVM это просто грамотный подход к разработки вашего приложения, где все делится на 3 слоя (Model-View-ViewModel), тут нет нечего такого прям страшного, просто пару простых правил, которые в дальнейшем будут экономить вам время и нервы)

Comment: Спасибо Вам!!!!!

Comment: @Евгений Да не за что! Если ответ помог, то не забудьте отметить его. Ну а так пишите если что, постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Я Вас понял!!!!

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как установить первую пустую строку в dataGrid т.е., без данных которые вы установили в MainViewModel().

Comment: Я пытался сделать как:  public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items = null; но остаются только заголовки.

Comment: @Евгений Вы поймите суть привязок. У вас есть коллекция, которая инициализирована и привязана. Вы не трогаете ее инициализацию больше не как (то есть не делаете, `=null` или `= new..`), ибо вы потеряете привязку!  Вы можете без проблем работать с элементами внутри этой коллекцией. К примеру, добавить в начало списка что то - `items.Insert(0, item);`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.